# Import aar of Android library in Python

Tags: android, python, aar

I have wrote an Android library and build an aar file. And I want to write a python program to use the aar library. Is it possible to do that? If so, how to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to include all dependencies to your aar file. So According to the open source licenses you can add their sources to your project.